# Hollow diamond in python with an asterisk outline

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to build a hollow diamond like this one:

```
   ******
   **  **
   *    *
   *    *
   **  **
   ******
```

Heres what I have so far,

```
def hollow_diamond(w):
 h=int(w/2)
 while 0<h:
  print('*'*h)
  h=h-1
 i=1
 while i<(w/2+1):
  print(i*'*')
  i=i+1
```

However using the code that i have i only get half of the diamond.

```
***
**
*
*
**
***
```

Should I be using **for** loops instead of while to be able to complete the diamond?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Should you tag your question "homework"?

Comment: the homework tag has been burninated

Comment: Only half of the diamond is being printed? It sounds to me like you will have to design and implement an algorithm to get the other half. I wish you luck. If you have an actual question besides "my homework isn't done," that you can't resolve with thorough effort and research, let us know.

Comment: `print('\n'.join("*"*(w-i) + "  "*i + "*"*(w-i) for i in list(range(0, w, 2)) + list(range(w, 0, -2))))`

Answer (score 2):

You've already figured out how to print the first set of asterisks for each line; good job so far.  Now, you need to figure out how many spaces to print.  Let's take the first loop, where you're printing **h** asterisks in a grid of **w** lines.

You need **h** asterisks on the left and **h** more on the right; that's **2*h** asterisks total.  This leaves **s = w - 2*h** spaces in the middle.

So, for each line, you need to print ...

- **h** asterisks
- **s** spaces
- **h** more asterisks

Does that move you toward a useful update of your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Building a hollow diamond means, like you said, probably the following:

1. A line with full asterisks (`0` spaces in the middle)
2. A line with `2` spaces in the middle
3. A line with `4` spaces in the middle
4. ...
5. A line with `l-2` spaces in the middle
6. A line with `l-2` spaces in the middle
7. A line with `l-4` spaces in the middle
8. A line with `l-6` spaces in the middle
9. ...
10. A line with full asterisks (`l-l` spaces in the middle)

`n` is the "step", or how many asterisks you "lose" in each iteration. `l` is the size of your square.

So, you algorithm is composed of two parts, the increasing spaces, and the decreasing spaces.

So, your algorithm should be something like this

```
for (spaces = 0; spaces < size/2 ; spaces = spaces + 1 ) 
    for (asterisk = 0; asterisk < size/2 - spaces; asterisk = asterisk + 1)
        print '*'
    for (space = 0; space < spaces*2; space = space + 1) 
        print ' '
    for (asterisk = 0; asterisk < size/2 - spaces; asterisk = asterisk + 1)
        print '*'
for (spaces = size/2 - 1; spaces >= 0; spaces = spaces - 1) 
    # The same inner code as above
```

I purposedly didn't put the python code there, so you can do your homework properly ;), but once you understand the algorithm, that should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

I won't steal from you the joy to fix your homework but this exercise was quite fun so I'll give you another possible version to give you few ideas:

```
def cool_diamond(w):
    r = []
    for y in range(w):
        s = '*' * (w - y)
        r.append("{0}{1}{0}".format(s, ''.join(['-' for x in range(2 * y)]), s))

    return '\n'.join(r + r[::-1])

for i in range(3, 6):
    print cool_diamond(i)
    print('-' * 80)
```

I'd strongly recommend you take your time first to fix yours! Otherwise you won't learn nothing from the exercise.

Once you've fixed yours you'll feel pretty satisfied for the effort paying off, and then... just then, you can take think whether you can improve YOUR version or refactoring.

Happy coding!

```
******
**--**
*----*
*----*
**--**
******
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
********
***--***
**----**
*------*
*------*
**----**
***--***
********
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**********
****--****
***----***
**------**
*--------*
*--------*
**------**
***----***
****--****
**********
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, remember it is only for even numbers entered else the program will execute a number less than that. I have made a code for your requirement.

```
n=int(input('Enter a number'))
if n%2==0:
    pass
else:
    n-=1
    print("Works only for even number,so decremented the number by 1")
k=n//2    
print(a*n)
for i in range(1,k):
    print(a*(k-i),end='')
    print(b*(c),end='')
    print(a*(k-i),end='')
    print()
    c=c+2
c=c-2
for i in range(1,k):
    print(a*(i),end='')
    print(b*(c),end='')
    print(a*(i),end='')
    print()
    c-=2
print(a*n)
```

You can also use it as function. You can easily convert so. You can use both while and for loop.
Check out while loop.

```
a='*' ; b=' ';c=2
n=int(input('Enter a number'))
if n%2==0:
    pass
else:
    n-=1
    print("Works only for even number,so decremented the number by 1")
k=n//2
print(a*n)
i=1
while i<k:
    print(a*(k-i),end='')
    print(b*c,end='')
    print(a*(k-i),end='')
    print()
    c=c+2
    i+=1
c-=2
i=1
while i<k:
    print(a*i,end='')
    print(b*c,end='')
    print(a*i,end='')
    print()
    c-=2
    i+=1
print(a*n)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome. Please don't add unrelevant links to (personal) websites.